# Why does empty controllerName property work when the default action is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was reading up on URLs and Routes chapter in Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 and tried to see what happens when the object defaults contain empty values. This is the route I have at the moment.

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}", 
    new { controller="Home", action="Index" });
```

Following are observations I made with possible combinations of values of object defaults. (**In each case, URLs in BOLD are not accessible.**)

## Case 1

```
new { controller="Home", action="Index" });
```

1. http://mywebapp.net/
2. http://mywebapp.net/Home/
3. http://mywebapp.net/Home/Index/

## Case 2

```
new { controller="Home", action="" });
```

1. **http://mywebapp.net/**
   Error: The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty string value.
2. **http://mywebapp.net/Home/**
   Error: The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty string value.
3. http://mywebapp.net/Home/Index/

The above error with 2nd URL is because the routing system couldn't find a default action name.

## Case 3

```
new { controller="", action="" });
```

1. **http://mywebapp.net/**
   Error: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: controllerName
2. **http://mywebapp.net/Home/**
   Error: The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty string value.
3. http://mywebapp.net/Home/Index/

The above error with 1st and 2nd URLs is because the routing system couldn't find default controller and action names respectively.

## Case 4

```
new { controller="", action="Index" });
```

1. **http://mywebapp.net/**
   Error: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: controllerName
2. http://mywebapp.net/Home/ (How and why is this accessible?)
3. http://mywebapp.net/Home/Index/

---

When both `controller` and `action` properties are empty in **Case 3**, I received errors as expected. So in **Case 4**, how is 2nd URL http://mywebapp.net/Home/ accessible when I have an empty value for `controller` property?

Is it as simple as the 2nd URL being accessible because a HomeController is already defined and the routing system by found it by convention or is there some explanation for this behavior? Can this be modified to let the 2nd URL be inaccessible or does this violate the convention-over-configuration principle?

Comment: Case 4.1 works because you've specified the controller and there's a default action configured. I'm more concerned that Case 2.1 works, since there's no default action configured.

Comment: @RichardSzalay: Thanks for pointing it out. I think I overlooked it. **Case 2.1 also does not work**. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Home` and `Index` are not hardcoded conventions, unless you specify them as defaults the runtime won't attempt to find them.

Case 2.1 does not work because the URL did not contain a value for the `action` parameter, and there's no `action` default.

Case 4.1 does not work because the URL did not contain a value for the `controller` parameter, and there's no `controller` default.

I recommend [this post](http://maxtoroq.github.io/2012/04/putting-aspnet-routing-to-test.html) if you want more details about how routing works.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Not to sound arrogant, but I kind of understood why 2.1 and 4.1 did not work. Sorry I did not make that clear enough in my question. I was more curious to know whether 4.2 worked just because Home controller was present in the predefined location, since I did not specify a name for default Controller.

Comment: I forgot to mention that your blog post is very informative. Thanks for linking it.

Comment: @Nanda 4.2 works because the URL contains a value for the `controller` parameter, and you have a non-empty default for `action`. Default values are used only when the URL does not contain a value for the parameter.